# Almost There: Completely Smooth Trapezoid with CSS Skills

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I want to create a trapezoid with all corners rounded. I've gotten 2/4 of the way there but can't manage to get the bottom corners look nice. Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/w8rHk/2/

Color difference is for illustration only. It will be the same color in the end.

**Question:** How do I finish this and create a trapezoid with all nicely rounded edged?

1 million points if you can make it scale up and down for screen sizes with out it breaking. That's a ninja level I don't come close to approaching yet.

**Question 2:** Any way to put a gradient on this bad boy?

Thanks for the help!

## Code:

```
.trapezoid{
vertical-align: middle;
position:relative;
border-bottom: 120px solid blue;
border-left: 200px solid transparent;
border-top-left-radius:30px;
border-top-right-radius:30px;
*border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
height: 0;
width: 150px;}

.trapezoid:after {
content:' ';
left:-14px;
top:-10px;
position:absolute;
background:red;
border-radius:40px 30px 0 0;
width:164px;
height:40px;
display:block;
}​
```

Comment: Please update your post with a [_specific question_](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Too much of a hack: http://jsfiddle.net/w8rHk/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt lol

```
.trapezoid{
    position:relative;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 180px solid transparent;
    width: 122px;
}

.trapezoid:before{
    content:' ';
    left:-184px;
    top:98px;
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    border-radius:80px 20px 80px 80px;
    width:318px;
    height:20px;
}


.trapezoid:after {
    content:' ';
    left:-11px;
    top:-7px;
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    border-radius:150px 50px 90px 0px;
    width:133px;
    height:30px;
}

<div style="margin:30px">
    <div class="trapezoid">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bzj3h/